# Interest of typed variables in python functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, types

I saw that since python 3.6 it is possible to define the type of variables in python functions and I do not clearly understand all the interests apart displaying an error if the type passed during the call is not coherent.

For example, do we gain in speed or use of memory between these two functions?

```
def full_name (fname, lname):
   return fname + lname

def typed_full_name (fname: string, lname: string) -> string:
   return fname + lname
```

Comment: Python type annotations are not used for runtime type checking, they're used for static type checking by tools like MyPy. You don't gain any speed at runtime, and lose a bit of memory to the extra metadata. I'd recommend starting with https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/.

Comment: Type annotation are a declaration of intent - placed by the coder. Nothing hinders you to call those function with other types. If you ount those 2 things above on the net - which one would be clearer for you to how they are to use and what they return? Try calling `typed_full_name(20,22)` and see what happens. If your IDE supports checking  it will issue you warnings for the "misuse" of the functions - but nothing hinders you to execute them.